# How do I insert data from a Recordset into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, recordset

I have created a record set from Excel data, but I am not able to select the record set and insert the data into the database:

```
Sub insrt()

        Dim xlXML             As Object
        Dim adoRecordset      As Recordset
        Dim rng               As Range
Dim Conn_lyr
Dim ConnString_lyr
Dim Vsql_lyr As String

   Range("B6").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Set rng = Selection
        Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
        adoRecordset.Open xlXML

ConnString_lyr = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; SERVER=xxxxxxxx;UID=xxxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxx;"

Set Conn_lyr = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Vsql_lyr = "insert into " + Range("E1").Value + ".DBO." + Range("f1").Value + " select * from adoRecordset"

With Conn_lyr
.ConnectionString = ConnString_lyr
.Open
.Execute (Vsql_lyr)
End With
Conn_lyr.Close
Set Conn8 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert full ADO Recordset into existing ACCESS table WITHOUT LOOP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32821618/4088852).

Comment: i need help with inserting into SQL  database Table...

Comment: The only difference should be the connection string.

Comment: Not working... have tried modifying it in many ways..Any other solution pls

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description  of your problem

Comment: Any other approach is possible??