# How to actually unset (set to Nothing) COM-object property in Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ado

I am having problems adapting [this VBA/VB6 disconnected Recordset code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32830596/2746150) to Powershell. Setting to `Nothing` fails to translate:

```
'disconnect the recordset and close the connection
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

1st attempt (use $null):

```
$rs.ActiveConnection = $null

ERROR: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
ERROR: + $rs.ActiveConnection = $null
ERROR: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

2nd attempt (do not perform set to nothing):

```
$conn = new-Object -com "ADODB.Connection"
$rs = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"
$conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myserver;Database=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.Open()
$rs.CursorLocation = 3 # adUseClient '<<<< important!
$rs.Open("select * from mytable where 1<>1", $conn, 2, 4) # adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
#$rs.ActiveConnection = $null
$conn.Close()
$rs.AddNew()
...
ERROR: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
ERROR: + $rs.AddNew()
ERROR: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

**Note** that I am not interested in the alternate solutions such as `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, `ADOR` and `Out-DataTable`. I have tried them all and they are not suitable in my case.

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                              
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                              
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012                                                                                                                                                                                     
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                            
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                            
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1012                                                                                                                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                    
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Here the working source code for reference (it does work as VBA in Excel using ADO 6.1):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Long

    Set con = getConn()

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient '<<<< important!

    'get an empty recordset to add new records to
    rs.Open "select * from Table1 where false", con, _
             adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

    'disconnect the recordset and close the connection
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

    'add some new records to our test recordset
    For i = 1 To 100
        rs.AddNew
        rs("UserName") = "Newuser_" & i
    Next i

    'reconnect to update
    Set con = getConn()
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = con

    rs.UpdateBatch '<<< transfer to DB happens here: no loop!

    rs.Close 

    'requery to demonstrate insert was successful
    rs.Open "select * from Table1", con, _
            adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs("ID").Value, rs("UserName").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    con.Close
End Sub

Function getConn() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rv As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
     & "Data Source = " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.accdb"

    rv.Open strConn
    Set getConn = rv
End Function
```

**UPDATE:** Final working code (thanks to the answer below):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$src = Import-CSV -Path 'c:\mydata.csv'
$conn = new-Object -com "ADODB.Connection"
$rs = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"
$conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myserver;Database=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.Open()
$rs.CursorLocation = 3 # adUseClient '<<<< important!

#get an empty recordset with fields defined
$rs.Open("select * from mytable where 1<>1", $conn, 2, 4) # adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

#
#disconnect the recordset
#

# Create a wrapper for the value null as per ZiggZagg's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682554/2746150
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper]$nullWrapper = New-Object "System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper" -ArgumentList @($null);
# Get the the type for ADODB.Recordset as per ZiggZagg's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682554/2746150
[Type]$recordSetType = [Type]::GetTypeFromProgID("ADODB.Recordset", $true);
# Write the property ActiveConnection as per ZiggZagg's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682554/2746150
$recordSetType.InvokeMember([string]"ActiveConnection", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty, [System.Reflection.Binder]$null, [object]$rs, [object[]]@($nullWrapper));
# Close connection
$conn.Close()

#fillup code
Foreach ($row in $src) {
    $rs.AddNew()
    Foreach ($col in $row.psobject.Properties.Name) {
        $fld = $rs.Fields.Item($col)
        $fld.Value = $row.$col
    }
}

#reconnect
$conn.Open()
$rs.ActiveConnection = $conn

#final update
$rs.UpdateBatch()
$rs.Close()
```

This code is used for bulk loading of 10K-50K of rows with 100+ fields (varying). Similar code [using Out-DataTable](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/bulk-copy-data-sql-server-powershell) has ten times more lines (as each field has to be defined) and has similar performance.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You are closing the connection and then trying to call `AddNew`. Just do that the other way round.

Comment: @DavidG, it is about _disconnected_ recordset. And yes, is the other way round. Close the connection 1st and call AddNew afterwards.

Comment: Interesting stuff. `$Null` ought to work, but the PowerShell binders apparently don't handle this case correctly -- for whatever reason. By far the way of least resistance would be to keep this code as-is and use `cscript` to run it, or else migrate to anything using ADO.NET rather than classic ADO. But there really *ought* to be a solution in PowerShell itself.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, I have tried various combinations of `$conn.Close()`, `Clear-Variable conn` and `[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($rs.ActiveConnection)` - no luck. Indeed there are should be a PS solution to that. I suspect there is some code in property setter for ActiveConnection that marks recordset as 'Disconnected' when `Nothing` comes in.

Comment: $rs.ActiveConnection is not the COM object. So you cannot release it. $rs is the COM object you could release it but then it is all gone. Releasing the ***connection*** is a function of the object itself. Not a function of powershell.

Comment: @anton-krouglov I posted an article about Checking for Null maybe this will help with setting the object to null: https://powershellposse.com/2017/08/17/what-the-null/

Comment: This is exceedingly ugly, but if you call `Marshal::FinalReleaseComObject` on `$rs.ActiveConnection`, the recordset is disconnected. The drawback is that the connection becomes unusable entirely since it's disconnected from its wrapper as well, so you have to omit `$conn.Close()` and you can't reconnect the recordset afterwards. I'm not even sure this properly closes the connection. Use at your own peril.

Comment: I think cursor type should be adOpenStatic = 3. Dynamic cursors are server side cursors. Perhaps setting it to dynamic changes the cursor location to server

Comment: @AntonKrouglov forget about disconnected recordsets. They were replaced by datasets 15 years ago, which are disconnected by definition. Powershell is *.NET*. You should use ADO.NET classes. Better yet, use the SQL Server [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell) and [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps), eg: `Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\ScriptFolder\TestSqlCmd.sql" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\ScriptFolder\TestSqlCmd.rpt"`

Comment: The [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) command can return results as objects or datasets `$DS = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyComputer" -Query "SELECT  ID, Item FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable" -As DataSet;
$DS.Tables[0].Rows | %{ echo "{ $($_['ID']), $($_['Item']) }" };`

Comment: As I have stated, contemporary methods just do not apply in my particular case. Good old disconnected recordset does the job in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit I am not sure whether or not the following does the same as your VBA script. Would you mind checking if it does what your are expecting?

```
# Create a wrapper for the value null
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper]$nullWrapper = New-Object "System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper" -ArgumentList @($null);
# Get the the type for ADODB.Recordset
[Type]$recordSetType = [Type]::GetTypeFromProgID("ADODB.Recordset", $true);
# Write the property ActiveConnection
$recordSetType.InvokeMember([string]"ActiveConnection", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty, [System.Reflection.Binder]$null, [object]$rs, [object[]]@($nullWrapper));
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked. Just some minor quirks needs to be added - see update in the question.