# Bulk Load from local access DB to linked ODBC SQL Server updateable Table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc

I am new to stackoverflow, so forgive me if I break any forum rules.  I currently use MS-Access as a front-end view to many ODBC-linked SQL server tables. My issue arises when I try to load a single column of data from a local table to an "updateable" table on the SQL server.  Just pasting in 10k records takes upwards of 15 minutes and I'm looking for a solution on how to use a VB module to reduce this time. Using this link, [How to increase performance for bulk INSERTs to ODBC linked tables in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863473/how-to-increase-performance-for-bulk-inserts-to-odbc-linked-tables-in-access/25879264), I was able to create a macro that runs at about the same speed as just pasting in, but I really need to increase the speed since it's just **too slow**.

My local table name is **[tblTempSmartSSP]** which contains one field **(circuits)**

My SQL Server ODBC-Linked table **[dbo_REF_CIRCUIT_LIST_UPDATEABLE_RM]** has a matching field name **(circuits)**

```
Sub PtqTest()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim t0 As Single, i As Long, valueList As String, separator As String

t0 = Timer
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT circuits FROM tblTempSmartSSP", dbOpenSnapshot)
i = 0
valueList = ""
separator = ""
Do Until rst.EOF
    i = i + 1
    valueList = valueList & separator & "(" & rst!circuits & ")"
    If i = 1 Then
        separator = ","
    End If
    If i = 1000 Then
        SendInsert valueList
        i = 0
        valueList = ""
        separator = ""
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
If i > 0 Then
    SendInsert valueList
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
Debug.Print "Elapsed time " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0") & " seconds."
End Sub

Sub SendInsert(valueList As String)
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_REF_CIRCUIT_LIST_UPDATEABLE_RM").Connect
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.SQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_REF_CIRCUIT_LIST_UPDATEABLE_RM (Circuits) VALUES 
" & valueList
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you provide!!

Ryan

Comment: Be careful here. This is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves this type of code. http://bobby-tables.com/ You need to use properly parameterized queries here instead of building up a string and executing it.

Comment: Why arent you using transferspreadsheet or transfer text? Or some kind of join that checks for primary key = null?

Comment: You can try a [disconnected ADO recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32830596/7296893). I highly recommend using recordsets above queries, that alleviates the risk of SQL injection too.

Comment: Are you just appending data? Just  use an append query from the local table to the linked table. Definitely stay away from looping one record at a time in code